# How do I get a count of users and web pages by sub-domain using Dynatrace or Google Analytics?

Tags: web, google-analytics, monitor, dynatrace

I work at a company with a website which is translated to 3 languages. We are trying to price out some competitors language translation services and they asked for some page load metrics. Each language has its own subdomain for instance:

- spanish: es.mydomain.com
- french: fr-ca.mydomain.com
- english: www.mydomain.com

I am trying to figure out how many total users hit the site (based on session) and also the total number of pages loaded on each domain/language over the last year (for instance 3000 sessions hit the french page and a total of 30000 pages were loaded).

We have dynatrace and google analytics but Im struggling to figure out where to find this information. Seems like it should be available somewhere. Google Analytics doesn't seem to report anything based on sub-domain. Dynatrace is probably my best bet but its so vast I cant seem to figure out the exact right place to look (seems like its used more for error monitoring than analytics tracking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Analytics you can just use a custom filter.

Go to the pages report, set the time period you want (keep in mind GA samples data so it won't be exact), add a secondary dimension that includes the full hostname or full URL.

Then use the "search box" to search for "www.", then "es.", then "fr-".

If that isn't sufficient enough for some reason, just get more specific with your search/filter, it supports RegEx so you can be as specific as you need to but adding the secondary dimension to the report is the key part.

Comment: thanks this works like a charm. I did not get a chance to test out the other suggestions as this works but they might also work.

Answer (score 1):

In Dynatrace the [USQL](https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/how-to-use-dynatrace/real-user-monitoring/how-to-use-real-user-monitoring/cross-application-user-session-analytics/custom-queries-segmentation-and-aggregation-of-session-data/) query language is well suited for analysis like that.

You can do something like the following to count either tagged users or detected users per domain:

```
SELECT useraction.domain, count(DISTINCT userId) AS taggedUsers, count(DISTINCT internalUserId) AS detectedUsers 
FROM usersession 
GROUP BY useraction.domain
```

You can use the "query editor" which is available via the menu item "User sessions" and then the button "User session query", it has nice auto completion, so it is easy to play around with the query-language there.

Afterwards use the "pin to dashboard" to add it as tile to the dashboard.

You can slice and dice the result quite flexibly and choose the timeframe via the global timeframe selection on the page.

Note however that the data is available here for 35 days at max.

Comment: the above GA solution works so did not get a chance to test your solution but thanks for posting! I will play around with it as well when I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create 3 segments based on hostname, like this generic example:

[image]

So you can see in the reports traffic data on those hosts.

Comment: What you're describing is actually setting up a "custom filter", I realized I mis-used the term in my answer. Unfortunately, custom filters and segments don't apply retroactively but what you describe is definitely the right way to handle it going forward. Note, before you start applying filters to your data you should create a new "view" and apply filters to those views so you always have 1 unfiltered view with raw data just in case.

Comment: It is not a custom filter, but a segment. It allows you to analyze groups of data according to the rules you define. It can be applied to post acquisition data, if you remove the segment the data will return to the overall one. Instead, a filter prevents data from ending up in the view. In your case, since you cannot process historical data, you can use a segment to analyze them separately in the view. If you want to collect them separately in different views, for future data, you have to use filters.